# Not able to draw regression line in R

Tags: r, plot, linear-regression

I am trying to generate a x-y plot in R with the regression line on the same plot. I am using **cars** dataset. So I tried:

```
plot(dist ~speed, data = cars, pch = 16); 
abline(coef(cars))
```

But it only drew the x-y plot, but didn't draw the regression line.

Comment: You need, abline(summary(lm(dist ~speed, data = cars)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
abline(summary(lm(dist ~speed, data = cars)))
```

The above is the code you're after (I think).

Comment: `abline(lm(dist ~speed, data = cars))` is sufficient.